# The relationship of signed measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite signed measures. Show that there is a signed measure $\mu \wedge \nu$ which is smaller than $\mu$ and $\nu$, but larger than any signed measure which is smaller than $\mu$ and $\nu$. Also prove that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are positive, then they are mutually singular if and only if $\mu \wedge \nu=0$. ($hint$ show that $\mu \wedge \nu =\dfrac{1}{2}(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|)$)

The only thing I think I can resort to is the Jordan decomposition. But I don't know how to deal with the $|\mu-\nu|$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|)=\min\{\mu,\nu\}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to think of this in terms of RN derivative. Let $\lambda$ be any measure that dominates both $\mu$ and $\nu$, e.g. $\lambda = |\mu| + |\nu|$, and let $f$ and $g$ be the corresponding RN derivatives. What about
$$
  \kappa(\cdot)= \int_{\cdot}\min(f,g)\mathrm d\lambda
$$